# Manually triggering code action suggestion in VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to make a VSCode extension to only return the code action when the "lightbulb" code action suggestion feature is manually invoked?

I am trying to make a VSCode extension using TypeScript that suggests a code snippet when the user invokes the "lightbulb" code action suggestion feature on a specific line. However, I want the code action to only be returned when the user manually invokes the "lightbulb" code action suggestion feature and not when the code action is triggered automatically.

I have tried to check the context.trigger property in the provideCodeActions method, but it does not exist on the CodeActionContext type. I also tried to check the context.only property, but it does not have the contains method.

Is there a way to achieve this feature?

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCodeActionsProvider('python', {
        provideCodeActions: async (document, range, context, token) => {
            const action = await suggestfix(document, range, context);
            return action ? [action] : [];
        },
    }));
};
```

Comment: when is a code action triggered automatically

Comment: @rioV8 right now the code action is being triggered automatically every time I click on function or class names. Trying to prevent that from happening.

Comment: That too not just once but thrice sometimes.

Comment: most likely it is triggering the: **request for possible code actions** automatic or multiple times, how else could it display a light bulb, the user has to select an action to perform, you can postpone the calculation of what to do